# Necessidade de SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Quero esclarecer a seguinte dúvida: Tenho um projeto `Android` que usa um `webservice`, porém fiz toda a parte de acesso a dados em `Android` e  meu `webservice` será feito em  `Java`.

Depois que terminei todas as classes fiquei pensando na necessidade do `Sqlite` nessa ocasião, já que não usarei ele para autenticar usuários e trazer informações de outros usuários.

Então, fiz toda minha camada de dados com CRUD's complexos em vão ?
Quero saber se como a minha aplicação é online eu não precisaria de um banco `Sqlite`?

Comment: É difícil dizer ao certo, sem ver, sem entender sua necessidade. Mas é provável que sim, a maioria dos programadores hoje dia fazem muita coisa que não precisa, muito provavelmente porque querem ver a casa pronta, mas não entendem o que precisa para fazer a casa. Se tiver mais informações, eu posso tentar responder.

Answer (score 1):

> De maneira direta, se você **não** precisa salvar dados no dispositivo, não precisa de SQLite.

Não há motivos para adicionar algo em seu código que você não irá utilizar (vide exceção).

Vamos ao seu exemplo.

Se você irá enviar todas as informações para um Web Service e retornar todos os dados do mesmo, não irá utilizar o SQLite. Agora, o seu CRUD pode ou não ter sido em vão, isso depende de como está arquitetado o seu sistema. Se irá salvar os dados no Web Service, você só precisa alterar a forma de salvar de um CRUD SQLite para o envio de dados ao Web Service. A forma de fazer isso depende muito da arquiteura que está utilizando, mas foi apenas um exemplo.

**Então eu não devo utilizar?**

Bom, aí fugimos um pouco do seu caso específico e falamos de aplicações.

Necessidade de utilizar não tem, porém, é muito comum utilizar por questões de conectividade. Nem sempre a pessoa terá acesso à Internet, e perder tudo o que foi feito (dependendo da aplicação) seria uma experiência ruim para o usuário.

Agora, se deseja que sua aplicação funcione apenas quando o aparelho possuir internet, você não precisa desses dados.

Indo um pouco além, mesmo que sua aplicação irá retornar todos os dados do Web Service, pode haver casos onde é mais performático e menos "custoso" ao usuário realizar uma única consulta no Web Service e salvar o retorno no SQLite. Imagine o sistema fazer uma requisição ao Web Service a cada página apenas para obter o nome do usuário logado? Isso consumiria internet e seriam várias requisições ao Web Service que poderia ser tratado apenas salvando os dados no SQLite.

Agora, como foi dito [pelo @Maniero em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171236/necessidade-de-sqlite#comment352872_171236), não é possível responder dizer ao certo se irá precisar ou não. Somente você conhece o escopo do projeto e o que ele realmente irá precisar.

Comment: Entendi, então seria mais prático, por exemplo, eu guardar no sqlite informações de acesso rápido e de busca frequente, como usuário logado ou por exemplo lista de amigos e lista de eventos daquele usuário? o app básicamente funciona como um registro de evento de usuarios e seus "amigos" à estabelecimentos.

Comment: @Josué Isso depende muito da sua necessidade. Por exemplo, se deseja salvar informações do usuário, deverá garantir que esses dados sejam modificados caso houver alterações. Se tudo é feito no App, isso é simples. Agora, se possuir alguma outra forma de inserção fora do App, isso pode ser um pouco mais complicado.

Comment: Todavia, a ideia é essa mesmo

Answer (score 0):

É **relativo**, porque depende de como tu vai querer que tua aplicação funcione.

Alguns meses atrás, eu fiz um aplicativo que mostrava eventos da cidade recebendo os dados por `JSON`, eu não utilizei um banco de dados porque não precisei salvar os eventos **offline** e é nesse caso que tu deve pensar.
Se você deseja salvar as informações no dispositivo, para que o usuário acesse sem precisar rodar o `webService` toda vez que abrir o aplicativo, use o `SQLite`. Se caso você não precisar disso, o aplicativo funcionará normalmente, mas as informações irão vir sempre que o usuário pedir.

Para ser mais preciso, pense no **usuário**. Pense como o **usuário**, não como **desenvolvedor**. Veja se você, como usuário, gostaria que uma aplicação só funcionasse com internet, sabendo que uma hora ou outra você vai estar sem conexão.

Comment: Agora tu abriu minha mente, o app é para marcação de eventos e conversação entre usuários, seria realmente interessante ter esses eventos disponíveis offline, não tinha pensando desta maneira. Obrigado!

Comment: <3... Ah, uma coisa que esqueci de citar, eu salvava os eventos no MySQL, mas permitia os usuários comentarem nos eventos e eu salvava os comentários deles também no MySQL, sem salvar no dispositivo. Mas novamente, não dava pra visualizar offline. Como eu disse, pense mais no usuário, na experiência que ele vai ter... E de nada!